# Handling type differences when calling c# dll from java code

Tags: java, c#, dll, java-native-interface

I have a dll library written in c#, I load dll into my java program by using `System.load("Link");`. I declare the method I want to call as `public native void Main (String s);`. Yet since String in java and string in C# is not compatible, thus the java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError exception is thrown. Can someone suggest me a solution for this ?

I want to code manually using java JNI thus please don't recommend to me external libraries.

Thank you very much.